# Elixir tight-loop speed up

Tags: erlang, native, elixir

I'm looking for ways to speed up the "tight-loop" in my elixir program.

```
Enum.reduce( list, 0, fn ({c,v},acc) -> v*elem(tuple_array,c) + acc end )
```

It's simply running through a list of tuples and for each it's doing:
a tuple lookup (c is an integer),
a multiplication, and 
an addition.

I tried inserting in the module's head

```
@compile [:native, {:hipe, [:verbose, :o3]}]
```

and on macOS it shows it compiling native.
Yet when I go and run the code from the iex shell 
it runs even slower than before.
Am I missing something here?

**UPDATE 3 May 2015**
I have now come to realize that my tight-loop is running at speeds nearly equivalent to compiled languages like Fortran - well not orders of magnitude slower.  My real bottleneck seems to be the sending of the output of that loop to another process - especially when this happens between nodes on a network.

Thanks to all who have shown interest.

Comment: okay may be the answer is to use an Erlang Native Implemented Function for this bit of code - using gcc to compile it.  Let's see ...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with pattern matching? Usually its faster than using Enum.reduce which under the hood uses lists:foldr

```
defmodule Test do
  def reduce_list([], acc, f) do
    acc
  end

  def reduce_list([h|t], acc, f) do
    reduce_list(t, f.(h, acc), f)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks rorra, but get no appreciable speed up using your module.  I guess Enum.reduce is doing a good optimisation to Erlang already.